# How can I list all messages a specific user posted in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-search

When you search for messages using chat search, you can **narrow down** the regular text search by specifying (1) room and (2) which user posted the messages.

However, if you specify the room and the user but leave the text search field blank, the chat search returns zero results.

How can I list all the chat messages posted by a specific user in chat? (if that makes the task easier, assume user is the one doing the search and only within a specific chatroom).